# find total distance cycled between two dates from google maps

Tags: google-maps

Is it possible to get the distance traveled by a particular mode of transportation via google maps, either api's or another method?

I cannot see functionality that directly provides that functionality. Appreciate suggestions or pointers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your question: `"Is it possible to get the distance traveled by a particular mode of transportation via google maps, either api's or another method?"`, the answer is, yes.  The selection of the mode is accomplished using the `mapdist()` function and entering the choosen mode as an argument.  The google link and related documentation is pasted below.

Travel modes:

For the calculation of distances, you may specify the transportation `mode` to use. By default, distances are calculated for driving mode. The following travel modes are supported:

- `driving` (default) indicates distance calculation using the road
  network. walking requests distance calculation for walking via
  pedestrian paths & sidewalks (where available).
- `bicycling` requests distance calculation for bicycling via bicycle paths & preferred
  streets (where available).
- `transit` requests distance calculation via
  public transit routes (where available). This value may only be
  specified if the request includes an API key or a Google Maps
  Platform Premium Plan client ID. If you set the mode to `transit` you can optionally specify either a `departure_time` or an `arrival_time`. If neither time is specified, the `departure_time` defaults to now (that is, the departure time defaults to the current time). You can also optionally include a transit_mode`enter code here` and/or a `transit_routing_preference`.

Note: Both walking and bicycling routes may sometimes not include clear pedestrian or bicycling paths, so these responses will return warnings`enter code here` in the returned result which you must display to the user.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview#travel-modes